# Issue while adding Font Awesome in Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts, font-awesome

I am trying to FontAwesome in my iPhone app. I have set Up all things.

But every time I am getting this `?(question)mark Image` . I am sure that I have added the font Correctly In my Project and also in Plist:

Here is my Project Setup:

#### Step 1:

Added Font Awesome File in My project

[image]

#### Step :2

Installed Font Awesome in my Mac.

[image]

#### Step : 3

Add Key In my `pList` File.

[image]

#### Step 4:

For Confirmation Checked the Font List in Storyboard:

[image]

#### Step 5:

Created a `UILabel` Programmatically and setting font like this:

```
 UILabel *lblFontAwesome = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 400)];
lblFontAwesome.center = self.view.center;
lblFontAwesome.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:35];
[lblFontAwesome setText:@"\uf014"];

[self.view addSubview:lblFontAwesome];
```

#### Step 6: I have added Some Category files also.

[image]

#### Step 7:

Here what I am getting:

[image]

I tried different solutions on net and also from SO.One is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569878/how-to-integrate-and-use-font-awesome-with-objective-c-or-swift-in-an-xcode-proj)
.
But None of them seems to work. I am always getting this `?`.

**Note** when i try `%C` then I am getting this Image: [image]
And yes with a warning:
and Also this is not the correct icon. It's just showing unknown image.

[image]

Comment: did u add the NSString+FontAwesome category ?

Comment: Yes I have added that

Comment: Try running the code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16788493/3937 -- do you see your font? Is your fontName correct?

Comment: Strange I am getting this list http://pastebin.com/PGBu23eC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am sure that I have added the font Correctly In my Project and also in Plist

Well, *don't* be sure. Clearly you have *not* added it correctly.

The problem is that, although the font file is in your *project*, it is not being copied into your *app*. Thus, it is not available in the running app.

Here's how to fix that.

In the project navigator (your first screen shot), select the FontAwesome.ttf file. Now look at the File inspector on the right. Now look at the Target Membership section. Make sure that the app target is *checked*.

Comment: Now I have added but even then I am not getting icons :(

Comment: Also please note that nothing you can do will cause FontAwesome to work in your launch screen. It will work only in the app once it has _finished_ launching.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. I would not expect setting the font in Interface Builder to work (your step 4 screen shot). You must set the font _in code_. And when you do, make sure you are getting its name right; I doubt that `"FontAwesome"` is its correct PostScript name.

Comment: Thanks Your advice works..And Is working fine . You save my day

Comment: I'm happy I was able to help!